# mutually_exclusive_group with optional and positional argument

Tags: python, argparse, docopt

I created an cli specification with [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) which works great, however for some reason I have to rewrite it to argparse

```
Usage:
    update_store_products <store_name>...
    update_store_products --all

    Options:
      -a --all     Updates all stores configured in config
```

How to do that?

What is important I don't want to have something like this:

```
update_store_products [--all] <store_name>...
```

I think it would be rather something like this:

```
update_store_products (--all | <store_name>...)
```

I tried to use [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group), but I got error:

```
ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, you should include [the shortest code necessary to reproduce the error in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Without it an answer is just a shot in the dark.

Now, I'm willing to bet your [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) definitions look a bit something like this:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--all', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('store_name', nargs='*')
```

The arguments in a mutually exclusive group must be optional, because it would not make much sense to have a required argument there, as the group could then only have that argument ever. The `nargs='*'` alone is not enough – the `required` attribute of the created [action](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action-classes) will be `True` – to convince the mutex group that the argument is truly optional. What you have to do is add a default:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--all', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('store_name', nargs='*', default=[])
```

This will result in:

```
[~]% python2 arg.py
usage: arg.py [-h] (--all | store_name [store_name ...])
arg.py: error: one of the arguments --all store_name is required

[~]% python2 arg.py --all
Namespace(all=True, store_name=[])

[~]% python2 arg.py store1 store2 store3
Namespace(all=False, store_name=['store1', 'store2', 'store3'])
```